# How to concatenate two strings?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, string-concatenation

The program is supposed to take two inputted strings, concatenate them, then print. This is the code I have right now and I am wondering how to go about this. I'm still new, so bear with me. Thanks in advance.

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
.STACK 4096

INCLUDE io.h

.DATA
Inputstr BYTE 100 DUP (?)
Inputstr2 BYTE 100 DUP (?)
Outputstr BYTE 100 DUP (?)
prompt BYTE "Enter a string", 0
displayLbl BYTE "Concatinated string", 0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC

input prompt, Inputstr, 100
lea esi, Inputstr
lea edi, Outputstr
push esi
push edi
cld

input prompt, Inputstr2, 100
lea esi, Inputstr2
lea edi, Outputstr
push esi
push edi
cld


whileNoNul:
cmp BYTE PTR [esi], 0
je endWhileNoNul
movsb
loop whileNoNul

endWhileNoNul:
mov BYTE PTR [edi], 0
pop esi
pop edi
output displayLbl, Outputstr

mov eax, 0
ret

_MainProc ENDP
END
```

My code is only printing my second input which is *Inputstr2*. It is supposed to print out both *Inputstr* and *Inputstr2* together.

Comment: It doesn't do anything with `Inputstr`: doesn't attempt to copy it, doesn't attempt to print it.  All there is, is copying `Inputstr2` into `Outputstr`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no assembly expert, but it looks like you're pushing data on register esi and edi twice, first for InputStr and then for InputStr2 - so won't the `pop esi` and `pop edi` have only the InputStr2 in it when the code executes the While?

Answer (score 0):

### Some fine points

If you are going to allow the user to input 2 strings of up to 99 characters each, then your program should define an *Outputstr* that is bigger than 100.

For a concatenation between *string1* and *string2*, you would normally place the *string1* **before** the *string2*. Your code currently begins by copying *string2* (and forgets to deal with *string1*).

The stack needs balancing: what you `push` also needs to come off! And just as important, you need to `pop` the registers in reverse order.

The `loop` instruction in `loop whileNoNul` depends on the ECX register. Your code did not prepare that register beforehand, so results will not be correct.

### A solution

There's nothing that needs pushing or popping here. First copy the *Inputstr1* **without** its terminating zero, then copy the *Inputstr2* **with** its terminating zero. And of course, in between you don't tamper with the EDI register!

```
  Inputstr1 BYTE 100 DUP (?)
  Inputstr2 BYTE 100 DUP (?)
  Outputstr BYTE 200 DUP (?)

  ...

  input prompt, Inputstr1, 100
  input prompt, Inputstr2, 100

  mov  esi, OFFSET Inputstr1
  mov  edi, OFFSET Outputstr
  cld

  jmp  while
contWhile:
  stosb
while:
  lodsb
  cmp  al, 0
  jne  contWhile

  mov  esi, OFFSET Inputstr2
until:
  lodsb
  stosb
  cmp  al, 0
  jne  until

  output displayLbl, Outputstr
```